# Node.js : Assign value in an array element then calculate score

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js

I have an array of ids that are the intersection of two arrays. I want to assign a value per element in the intersection array. Below is my incomplete code of how to proceed:

```
//intersection array
var interArray= ["5ghIJDpPoe3CfHMGu71E6T","69Saih0L7exhpURTx2TN3r","7biThmNOfzA4nZR9h2B6DL",
    "51m0PrZokFZNk5b5xptyzC","1XPta4VLT78HQnVFd1hlsK"];

//Edited getting score
function calculateScore (interArray, callback) {
   var tmp = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < interArray.length; i++) {
     tmp++;
   }
   var score = (tmp/22) * 0.5; //22 for example is the total length of the two arrays that were combined
   callback(null, score);
}
```

Is this procedure correct/efficient if I want to predict the similarity of two arrays?

P.S. I used underscore.js to get the intersection and this is running on a Node.js API service

Thank you!

**EDIT**

So basically I have two arrays. The first array is a collection of IDs from the user. The second array is a collection of IDs from users. These IDs refer to items that are referenced to to each

```
async.parallel([
   function(callback) {
     async.waterfall([getUser,getItems], 
       function(err, results) {
         callback(null, results);
     });
   },
   function(callback) {
     async.waterfall([getUsers,getItems], 
       function(err, results) {
         callback(null, results);
       });
   }
], function(err, results) {
     var currentUserArray = results[0]; //item ids from user
     var matchedUsersArray = results[1]; //item ids per user

     function mapUsersArray () {
         //Get the item ids per matchedUser
     }
     function getIntersection() {
        //Get intersection of currentUserArray and matchedUsersArray[i]
     }

     //Compute similarity/match score of ids of currentUser per matchedUser
});
```

Restating the questions: *Is this procedure correct or efficient? How can I calculate their similarity/match score? And since I mapped the matchedUsersArray, how can I get the matchedUser details again so I can send it as a response along with the matchScore*?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "similarity"? Please define what you want your code to do.

Comment: Where is the 22 coming from? How does your function know about it?

Comment: @naomik I've mapped the item ids array then got its length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit code improvement...

you have interArray.length directly, no need to use a tmp variable for that..

```
var interArray= ["5ghIJDpPoe3CfHMGu71E6T","69Saih0L7exhpURTx2TN3r","7biThmNOfzA4nZR9h2B6DL",
    "51m0PrZokFZNk5b5xptyzC","1XPta4VLT78HQnVFd1hlsK"];

function calculateScore (interArray, callback) {
   var score = (interArray.length/22) * 0.5; //22 for example is the total length of the two arrays that were combined
   callback(null, score);
}
```

I didn't understand the exact question though, are you asking the procedure of finding similarities between arrays? Because that depends on what kind of prediction are you doing, there are multiple algorithms that rely on different sets of data. The current code just is fine though it is somehow calculating the similarity.. But let's say we have two arrays of length 10 each, that have 5 values in common.. 
The interArray.length would be 5 and then it'd be 5/20 = 0.25 which should be 0.5 instead as I think as both arrays have half of the values in common..

so it should be:

score= interArray.length / (sum of lengths of all arrays/number of arrays)

e.g. for our case

score = 5/(20/2) = 0.5

Comment: hi. Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question to further clarify my point of view. :D

I think getting the similarity between the two is fine for now, but can you point me to an algorithm that will further increase the accuracy of the score? Thank you!

Comment: You can use Hamming distance algorithm.. 
It'll be great for your problem with minor tweaks..

Suppose we have two data sets (objects) : 

{1,4,3,2} and {9,4,7,2} 

Hamming distance is the number of values required by an object to change to make it equal to the second one.. 

So in our case, hamming distance is 2 (changing 1 and 3 to 9 and 7 respectively)